# How to replace unsupport utf8 character in java

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

Java doesn't support all utf-8 character,like

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Character cha = new Character('\uD841');
    System.out.println(cha.compareTo(Character.MIN_VALUE));
    String ts = "this is a test string";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(ts);
    sb.append(cha);
    ts = sb.toString();
    for(int i =0;i<ts.length();i++){
        System.out.println(Character.isLetter(ts.charAt(i)));
    }
}
```

It will print "this is a test String?"
How can I ensure which character is not support?

Comment: Your example won't print "this is a test String?", but a sequence of true/false lines. What would you expect it to print? You might also be interested in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#supplementary).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're seeing is not "Java doesn't support a character", it's "your console doesn't support that character" or "your platform default encoding doesn't support your character".

1. There's no such thing as a "UTF-8 character", it's a "Unicode character", if you insist
2. Java can handle all characters in the current Unicode standard just fine
3. When writing to a file or console, it uses an encoding to convert those characters to bytes (as that's the universal interface).
4. If you just print to `System.out` then it uses the platform default encoding. If the platform default encoding can't encode the character, then that character is converted to the replacement character (defaulting to `?`).

And last but not least: [`\uD841` is **not a valid Unicode character**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d841/index.htm)! It's a high surrogate value and those are explicitly excluded from the Unicode standard (because they are used in UTF-16 to encode characters outside of the BMP).

Comment: +1 Nice answer. A question: Java's `char` is just 16-bit, can it  handle 32-bit characters?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: no, it can't on its own, but `String` can be representing it with 2 `char` values (basically implementing UTF-16). You can access them directly with `String.getCodePointAt()` and related methods (which return `int` values).